# SQL function that accepts a principal mortgage amount

Tags: sql

Need quick help
Write a SQL function that accepts a principal mortgage amount, an annual percentage
rate (APR), and the number of years a mortgage will be paid back over. Calculate the
associated monthly mortgage payment according to the following annuity formula:
 =   +

(1+)
 ( −1
)
where:
A = Monthly Payment Amount
P = Principle (Initial) Mortgage Amount
i = APR / 12 = Monthly Interest Rate
n = years * 12 = Total Number of Payments
Be sure to specify that data types of the input arguments have enough significant digits to
account for realistic mortgage amounts (as large as in the millions of dollars) and APRs
(down to the sixth decimal place will be sufficient).

I wrote the code

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sen_08_monthlyPayment (pa numeric (6,2), apr numeric (6,0), yearr integer)
            RETURNS NUMERIC
            LANGUAGE plpgsql
            AS
            $$
                DECLARE
                    i NUMERIC (6,6) = apr/12;
                    n INTEGER = yearr * 12;
                    monthlyPayment NUMERIC (12,6);
                BEGIN
                    SELECT pa * (i + (i/ (POWER(1+i,n))-1)) INTO monthlyPayment;
                    
                    RETURN monthlyPayment;
                END;
            $$;
    

SELECT sen_08_monthlyPayment (250000.00, 0.04125, 30) AS monthlyPayment;
```

The output came as -248890.666791.

Comment: Hi - you haven’t actually asked a question. What is the issue? Is the value being returned incorrect and, if it is, what should the value be?

Comment: Hi, the output is wrong. It cannot be a negative value. It seems the select which I used to define the formula is incorrect.

Comment: OK - but the calculation in your function doesn't match the formula in your question ( =   +  (1+)  ( −1 ) ) . For example, the formula doesn't have a POWER symbol anywhere in it

Comment: Hi @NickW - Problem is I am not able to paste the formula properly. It is P (i + i/(1+i)^n - 1) i.e. denominator is (1+i) raise to power n and complete denominator is subtracted by 1.

Comment: @KunalSen please [edit] the question and add your details to the question, not by responding to comments. Comments are not part of the Q&A, so you should say something lik e"Sorry, I'll make that clear in my question" and then [edit] the question.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google shows that the standard monthly mortgage payment calculation returns a negative value - presumably because it is reducing the principle amount owed. So to make it positive just multiple the value by -1.

The formula should be (including the -1*n to get the final result positive:

```
(i *pa) / (1 - (POWER((1 + (i)), (-1*n))))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Original statement**:

```
SELECT pa * (i + (i/ (POWER(1+i,n)**)**-1)) INTO monthlyPayment;
```

There is a parenthesis misplaced in the equation, if you adjust it as seen below you will get an actual payment amount:

```
SELECT pa * (i + (i/ (POWER(1+i,n)-1))**)** INTO monthlyPayment;
```

Output goes from `-248890.67` to `1211.71`, which is an actual payment amount. I know this question is a bit old now but maybe this will help someone else in the future!